# write file read code with overflow

Tags: c, file-io, environment

Well, I try to play a bit with stack overflow and security cookies,
But its seem that most of the tutorial programs that people with POC tutorial with them are not compile with security cookies.

So i decide to create a program that take input from file and create a buffer overflow.
This is what I come out with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void manipulate(char *buffer)
{
    char newbuffer[80];
    strcpy(newbuffer, buffer);
}

int main()
{
    char ch, buffer[4096];
    char filename[] = "exploit.txt";
    int i = 0;
    FILE *inFile;

    inFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file !\n");
        getchar();
        return 1 ;
    }
    while (buffer[i] != EOF)
    {
        buffer[i++] = fgetc(inFile);
        manipulate(buffer);
        printf("The value of i is : %d\n", i);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

My problem is that I am always get `Can't open input file !\n`. even when i created "exploit.txt" in the same location and put some "aaaa" in it.

Comment: Use absolute filenane or use api to receive its path and post results. By the way, c sharp is not the best language to study buffer overflows. Stick to c.

Comment: "...in the same location..." The same location as **what** ?? Ex: Without a change in project configuration, the default working directory for a VC++ program run from the debugger is the **project** folder (i.e. where the .vcprojx file is located). Put your input file there (assuming this is running under msdev).

Comment: I put in in debug inside the project folder..

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you 'play' with stack overflow?

Comment: I want to write exploit that will pass SG.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of opening a file are correct. You can improve your program by using `errno` and `strerror` to inform the user of why the attempt to open the file failed.

```
 #include <errno.h>
 fprintf(stderr, "Error opening \"%s\": %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
```

I was able to successfully run your example program (ignoring the stack overflow portion) with no changes.

The issue is with the value of the current or present working directory which is used as the basis for the completing file path used to open any file.

You can check the program's working directory using either `getcwd()` from `<unixstd.h>` for Linux, BSD, and POSIX systems or `_getcwd()` from `<direct.h>` for some other type.

Nitpicking: The "txt" file extension is misleading when compared with the `fopen` opening in binary mode, as specificed by `rb`.